# Rails : How to display all the associated records from table B based on every records from table A

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have two tables A and B. A contains the dates and B contains description along with A_id column. table A and B has one to many association.

```
Table A
---------------
id  | datecol
----+----------
1   |   03/01/2019
2   |   02/01/2019
3   |   01/01/2019 


Table B

id   |  description    |  A_id
-----+-----------------+------      
1    |  GK1_02/02/2019 | 2
2    |  GK3_01/01/2019 | 3
3    |  GK2_01/01/2019 | 3
4    |  GK1_01/01/2019 | 3
5    |  GK1_01/01/2019 | 1
```

In my rails template I want to display the entries like as below:

```
01/01/2019 
 . GK1_01/01/2019

02/01/2019
 . GK1_02/02/2019

03/01/2019
 . GK1_02/02/2019
 . GK2_02/02/2019
 . GK3_02/02/2019
```

So basically, I want to display all the associated records from B for every entries in A.

Could someone please assist me in implementing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is a one-to-many relation. You can implement that with Active Record associations https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

For example your table A could be an Author model and your table B could be a Book model

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

So your controller could search for your authors

```
class CatalogController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @authors = Author.all
  end
end
```

On your view iterate over authors and theirs books(A.datecol as Author.name, B.description as Book.title )

```
<ul>
  <% @authors.each do |author| %>
    <li><span><%= author.name %></span>
      <ul>
        <% author.books.each do |book| %>
          <li><%= book.title %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Javier. I was missing list method.